# Lombok with SuperBuilder

Tags: java, inheritance, lombok

I have a Java project that uses Lombok ( a java library that automatically plugs into the editor and build tools )

```
@Getter
@SuperBuilder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = { "id" })
@ToString(of = { "id" })
public class DacContexte {

    private Long id;
...
}
```

and this one:

```
@Getter
@SuperBuilder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class DacContexteReturn extends DacContexte {
}
```

but when I do the builder:

```
return  DacContexteReturn.builder()
                .id(5L)
                .build();
```

I got this error:

```
Required type: DacContexteReturn
Provided: DacContexte
```

Comment: can you try without `@AllArgsConstructor` in `DacContexteReturn` this should solve your issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cannot reproduce.

```
> mkdir tmpDir
> cd tmpDir
> nano DacContexte.java

import lombok.*;
import lombok.experimental.*;

@Getter
@SuperBuilder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = { "id" })
@ToString(of = { "id" })
public class DacContexte {
    private Long id;
}

> nano DacContexteReturn.java

import lombok.*;
import lombok.experimental.*;

@Getter
@SuperBuilder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = { "id" })
@ToString(of = { "id" })
public class DacContexte extends DacContexteReturn {
    private Long foo;
}

> nano Test.java

class Test {
    void foo() {
        DacContexteReturn dcr = DacContexteReturn.builder().id(5L).build();
    }
}

> javac -cp ~/lombok.jar *.java
[ no errors or warnings ]
```

Check to make sure you're on the [latest lombok](https://projectlombok.org/download) (currently, 1.18.16), and if that doesn't solve the issue, check that you've accurately described the problem. If this error is occurring within eclipse or intellij, update the question.

Comment: i have the same issue, https://githubmemory.com/repo/rzwitserloot/lombok/issues/2826