# can lombok annotation create super constructor

Tags: java, class, intellij-idea, lombok

I have parents class:

```
@Controller
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ParentController {

    protected final HttpServletRequest request;
    protected final ITestServiceCont testServiceCont;}
```

My child class:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("test")
public class ChildController extends ParentController {

    private final TestService testService;

    public ChildController(HttpServletRequest request, ITestServiceCont testServiceCont, TestService testService) {
        super(request, testServiceCont);
        this.testService = testService;
    }
```

In my child's class I am using a simple constructor I would like to use the lombok annotation but it doesn't work. As far as I can find in the documentation it says it is not possible but is it really?
I have tried the @SuperBuilder annotation but when I convert it to a simple constructor I see that it does not take parameters from the parent class

Comment: Correct. `@RequiredArgsConstructor` requires a no-arg constructor. What's wrong with `@SuperBuilder`?

Comment: maybe I've got it wrong. Because I put annotations in both classes:
@SuperBuilder
@AllArgsConstructor?
I take example:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65324329/lombok-with-superbuilder
And this page https://devwithus.com/lombok-constructor-annotations/ said that "Lombok can’t generate automatically a constructor that calls a super constructor with parameters for a subclass."